# Parallel invocation of SQL script from shell

Tags: shell, sql-scripts

I am using below logic to execute an SQL in parallel

`PID_LIST="start"
while [ "$PID_LIST" ] 
do`

```
$count =0
if [ "z$PID_LIST" = "zstart" ]
then
PID_LIST=""
fi

for PID in $PID_LIST
do
    # echo "Checkpid $PID"
    if kill -0 $PID >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
    PID_LIST_TMP="$PID_LIST_TMP $PID"
    $count =`expr $count  + 1`
    fi
done
PID_LIST=$PID_LIST_TMP

if [ $more_re_to_process -eq "Y" ]
then
while [ $count -le $MAX_INSTANCE ]
do

    #prepare input for sql

    invoke SQL script sql1 with prepared one >LOG_$count
    PID_LIST = PID_LIST="$PID_LIST $!"

done
fi; done
```

In this example whenever any sql process finishes I am creating a new one. 
But the problem is that I end up creating a new log. I want that whenever I create a new SQL session it uses the the LOG file of process which is finished (if any).

Could someone tell How Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the shell handles arrays, you could store the PIDs as elements in an array and clear only the element if a process finishes, so that the indexes of the other processes remain the same; then in a loop for invoking new processes scan for cleared elements; with the array index `$count`, `>LOG_$count` *uses the the LOG file of process which is finished*.